# How to Retrieve Azure AD User Groups Using Firebase Authentication with Microsoft OAuth Provider

Tags: firebase, azure, firebase-authentication, oauth, azure-active-directory

I am working on a web application and using Firebase Authentication for user sign-in. My application needs to authenticate users via the Microsoft OAuth provider (specifically Azure Active Directory) and then retrieve the user's Azure AD group information.

I have successfully set up Firebase Authentication with the Microsoft provider for the basic login flow. However, I am not sure how to retrieve the user's Azure AD group information.

Any examples or guidance on how to achieve these steps in a TypeScript application using Firebase Authentication would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would need to:

- configure Azure AD to include group claims in tokens.
- update your Firebase project's Microsoft OAuth provider configuration.
- modify your application to handle group claims.

```
+----------------+              +-------------------+
|                |              |                   |
|  Azure AD      +<-------------+  Firebase Auth    |
|                |              |                   |
+-------+--------+              +---------+---------+
        |                                   |
        |                                   |
        v                                   v
+-------+--------+              +---------+---------+
|                |              |                   |
| Group Claims   |              |  Your TypeScript  |
| in Token       |              |  Application      |
|                |              |                   |
+----------------+              +-------------------+
```

See "[Configure optional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/optional-claims)":

- In the Azure portal, go to the Azure Active Directory service.
- Navigate to the App registrations and select your app.
- Under the "Token configuration", add a new group claim.
- Choose the options for how you want the groups to be returned in the token.

Then update your Firebase configuration:

- In the Firebase Console, go to the Authentication section.
- Under the Sign-in method tab, configure the Microsoft provider.
- Enter the Azure AD app's details (client ID and secret).
  You can see that process illustrated in "[Integrate Azure AD with Firebase and call MS Graph in a Node.js app](https://dev.to/425show/integrate-azure-ad-with-firebase-and-call-ms-graph-in-a-node-js-app-973#article-show-more-button) " from [Christos Matskas](https://dev.to/christosmatskas)

Finally, modify Your TypeScript Application:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

// Initialize Firebase
// 

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com'))
    .then((result) => {
    // The Microsoft OAuth Access Token.
    const token = result.credential.accessToken;

    // Now use the token to retrieve group information from Microsoft Graph API
    // 
    }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    // 
    });
```

After authentication, use the access token to call the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve group information.
Make sure your Azure AD app has the necessary permissions to read group data.

You can use the access token to make a request to the Microsoft Graph API.
Fetch the groups by making a GET request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf`.

```js
// previous code

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com'))
  .then(async (result) => {
    const token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // Fetch group data
    const groupResponse = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf', {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });

    const groups = await groupResponse.json();
    console.log(groups);
    // Handle groups here
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here
    console.log(error);
  });
```

---

As an alternative approach, you could:

- add the Microsoft OAuth provider to your Firebase project and enable it for authentication in your web application. That will allow Firebase to authenticate users with Microsoft OAuth credentials.
- use the [`firebase.auth()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth) in your TypeScript application to get the current user's object, which contains information about the authenticated user:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "your-api-key",
    authDomain: "your-auth-domain",
    databaseURL: "your-database-url",
    projectId: "your-project-id",
    storageBucket: "your-storage-bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "your-messaging-sender-id",
    appId: "your-app-id",
    measurementId: "your-measurement-id"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get the current user
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    // You can now access user details
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Once you have the currentUser object, you can use the [getIdTokenResult() method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtokenresult).
Warning: The token you get from `getIdTokenResult()` is a Firebase token, not the original Microsoft OAuth token. Firebase replaces the Microsoft token with its own token upon successful authentication. That Firebase token is used for Firebase services and is not suitable for making requests to the Microsoft Graph API.

So you need to obtain the original Microsoft OAuth access token, which is different from the Firebase token.
During the sign-in process with Firebase's `signInWithPopup` or `signInWithRedirect` methods, you receive a result object that contains a credential attribute. That credential includes the original OAuth access token from Microsoft.

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

// Initialize Firebase
// 

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com'))
    .then((result) => {
        // The original Microsoft OAuth Access Token
        const microsoftToken = result.credential.accessToken;

        // Now use this token to retrieve group information from Microsoft Graph API
        // 
    }).catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        // 
    });
```

Use the retrieved `microsoftToken` for making requests to the Microsoft Graph API. That is the token that contains the necessary claims and permissions for Azure AD.

Note: the Firebase token obtained from `getIdTokenResult()` is still useful within the context of Firebase services (like accessing Firestore or Firebase storage) but not for external services like Microsoft Graph API.

Note also that you will need to enable the Microsoft Graph API in your Azure AD tenant and grant your application permissions to access the API. You can do this by registering your application in the Azure Portal and configuring the necessary permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I do get an error from using the alternative approach. When calling the Microsoft Graph API, it returns a ""InvalidAuthenticationToken" error with the message "Required claim nbf not present in token". Are you sure the token I get from `getIdTokenResult()` is the Microsoft OAuth token and not the one replaced by Firebase? :)

Comment: @KrisD.J. True, good point. I have rewritten the last part of the answer.

Comment: So there's no way to get the Microsoft OAuth token AFTER the user has logged in?

Comment: @KrisD.J. I think so: The original OAuth token from Microsoft is not stored or made easily accessible after the initial authentication process: Firebase processes the authentication and issues its own token (Firebase token) for use within Firebase services. The most straightforward approach is to capture and securely store the Microsoft OAuth token at the time of login.